# How to use Google Forms without iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-sheets, google-forms

Some years ago, I found on internet how to use Google forms inside a contact page only using a query in the attribute submit button action without iframe. Now, I can't find it anymore. Is it still possible to use Google forms without iframe?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just found it!

```js
 function postToGoogle() {
   var field1 = $("input[type='radio'][name='qs1']:checked").val();
   var field2 = $('#feed').val();

   $.ajax({
     url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdjOTKRb7YiWi8OGPq6M6CRL0TpuAsUKacKp2XgruMbIp4wzg/formResponse",
     data: {
       "entry.924752166": field1,
       "entry.997497831": field2
     },
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "xml",
     statusCode: {
       0: function() {
         //Success message
       },
       200: function() {
         //Success Message
       }
     }
   });
 }

/* 
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#form').submit(function() {
     postToGoogle();
     return false;
   });
   
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<strong>Test Google Form</strong>
<form id="form" target="_self" onsubmit="" action="javascript: postToGoogle()">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Question 1</label>
    <input id="qs1_op_1" type="radio" value="Yes" name="qs1" />
    <input id="qs1_op_2" type="radio" value="No" name="qs1" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label>Text</label>
    <textarea id="feed" name="feed"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <div style="width: 100%; display: block; float: right;">
    <button id="send" type="submit">
      Send
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<br /><br />
The <a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bVeLfK2gm6emaGRKHnMllpeb_P4HwwZoIfZB5MCcyZg/pubhtml">Result</a> takes few minutes to be shown, but it is sent to the google sheet instantaneously. 
<br /><br />
```

It's working in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/DonnyBrooker/pen/NbNNrw).

- [Sending data to Google docs from your web page, using your own form
  and AJAX!](https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000)

Comment: Does this still work in 2023

Answer (score 5):

This post is old, since one person has asked how it is done, it may be useful for some people.
I am not sure if it still works or not. Google update their services,
so here is  how it works:

- You can use this online form builder, [on W3chools](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZG7N7WTWTUQ), open it on a new tab.
- make a google form from google drive, when done adding your input, click preview your form, click the view source page of the loaded form page, let it be open on a new tab.
- search the source page of your google form for **entry.** , you should find something similar to **entry.1600284689**, notice the text before the entry for the matching input name, like name, or last name or email, copy the number.
- go to the form link from w3school above, and search for **entry.**, you should find the matching input in the left panel, paste it there, do the same for another input name.
- on your form preview source code search for:  **<form action=** and copy what is in front of it, go back to form link from w3school and find the  <form action= and replace it with the id over there, you are done.
- now test the form, fill the form and click submit, if everything was inserted correctly you should get the submitted info in your google form. when testing is OK, copy the whole HTML code from the left panel save it in a text file, it is ready to be used in your page or sidebar of your page.
  there was a video on Youtube on this, if you search you will find it.

I hope it is useful.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="container_form">
        <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQFctGBxto0NgsBi9R9dSXKT8Y0bUirmHjcisfnxnraMLeTw/formResponse">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="question" for="Nom">Nom</label>
            <input class="choice" type="text" name="entry.1490810163" required placeholder="Votre nom">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="question" for="">Prénom</label>
            <input class="choice" type="text" name="entry.1335381530" required placeholder="Votre nom">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="question" >Quelle est ta promotion ?</label>
            <div class="choice">
                <div  class="radio_align">
                    <input  type="radio" id="" name="entry.2014955126" value="Poincaré" required>
                    <label  for="entry.2014955126">Poincaré</label>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.2014955126" value="Onsager" required>
                    <label for="entry.2014955126">Onsager</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.2014955126" value="Noether" required>
                    <label for="entry.2014955126">Noether</label>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.2014955126" value="Meitner" required>
                    <label for="entry.2014955126">Meitner</label>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.2014955126" value="Langevin" required>
                    <label for="entry.2014955126">Langevin</label>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.2014955126" value="Ancien(ne) étudiant(e) ESEO" required>
                    <label for="entry.2014955126">Ancien(ne) étudiant(e) ESEO</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.2014955126" value="__other_option__" required>
                    <label for="entry.2014955126">Ancien(ne) étudiant(e) ESEO</label>
                    <input class="lign" type="text" name="entry.2014955126.other_option_response">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="question" for="">Quel âge as-tu ? </label>
            <input class="choice" type="text" name="entry.1170833208" required placeholder="Votre age">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="question" for="">As-tu déjà randonné en montagne ?</label>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.1404980088" value="Oui à balle je surkiffe" required>
                    <label for="entry.1404980088">Oui à balle je surkiffe</label>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.1404980088" value="Oui quelques fois" required>
                    <label for="entry.1404980088">Oui quelques fois</label>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.1404980088" value="Jamais ça sera une grande première" required>
                    <label for="entry.1404980088">Jamais ça sera une grande première</label>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="question" for="">Est-ce que tu follow Electrond'arbre sur les réseaux ?</label>
            <div class="choice">
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.284067721" value="Évidemment d'ailleurs le resp com gère trop de ouf (il est célibataire)" required>
                    <label for="entry.284067721">Évidemment d'ailleurs le resp com gère trop de ouf</label>  
                </div>
                <div class="radio_align">
                    <input type="radio" id="" name="entry.284067721" value="Non (éliminatoire)" required>
                    <label for="entry.284067721">Non (éliminatoire)</label>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label class="question" for="entry.1600021664">En quelques mots, peux-tu nous décrire ta motivation pour réaliser ce trek avec nous ? </label>
            <input class="choice" type="textarea" name="entry.1600021664" required placeholder="Votre réponse">
            </input>
        </div>
        <input class="button_form" type="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it