# fetch POST request saving data but returning ok as false while saving data to Google spreadsheet using Google form

Tags: javascript, fetch, google-forms

I have found a way to save data from form to google spreadsheet directly using some code from POST request of Google forms.
Here are the steps I followed.

1. Make  a google form and then open it in preview mode.
2. Open Network tab in DevTools and now fill the google form and submit it.
3. Now Right click on the `formResponse` and copy it using `copy as fetch` option.
   [image: logging the response]
4. Now to use it your own form add event listener of event submit and paste copied code in `script` tag.
5. replace the hardcoded value with a variable in `body` of the fetch request.

Here is sample code of how my script looks like

```
    newsletterForm = document.querySelector('#newsletter-form');
      newsletterForm.addEventListener('submit', ()=>{
        event.preventDefault();
    
    email_value = document.querySelector('#newsletter-input').value;

/*copied code*/
    fetch(...
      ......
      "body": `entry.1649101552=**${email_value}**...., 
      "method": "POST",
      "mode": "no-cors",
       
    }).then((res)=>console.log(res));
    
    /*copied code*/
      });
```

This does save my data from local to spreadsheet but when I log the response it is coming as false. Why is it happening ?

[image: 22]

Answer (score 0):

["no-cors"
Restricts requests to using CORS-safelisted methods and CORS-safelisted request-headers. Upon success, fetch will return an opaque filtered response.](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-request%E2%91%A2%E2%91%A0)

[An opaque filtered response is a filtered response whose type is "opaque", URL list is the empty list, status is 0, status message is the empty byte sequence, header list is empty, and body is null.](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque)

[More about CORS of Google Form by sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44037370/16125139)